# why does the following lines of code return an empty data set

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i expect to **scrape** the details of jobs form this url:https://www.indeed.com/q-doctor-l-Washington,-DC-jobs.html. I want to get a data frame that shows the job title,, the hiring organization,the location of the job and a summary of the job

```
import bs4
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re

res=requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/q-doctor-l-Washington,-DC-jobs.html")
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
jobs=soup.findAll(class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard')
full_dict={'title':[],'organization':[],'location':[],'summary':[]}

for job in jobs:
    job_title=job.find('div',{'class':'title'})
    job_organization=job.find('div',{'class':'company'})
    job_location=job.find('div',{'class':'sjcl'})
    job_summary=job.find('div',{'class':'summary'})
    full_dict['title'].append(job_title)
    full_dict['organization'].append(job_organization)
    full_dict['location'].append(job_location)
    full_dict['summary'].append(job_summary)

df=pd.DataFrame(full_dict)
print(df)
```

what is the error in my code ? why does it return an empty data frame?

Comment: There could be many reasons. What have you tried, to debug it? What does the `soup.findAll` statement return, for example?

Comment: "Jobs" is empty, no load any data.

Comment: Totally unreleated, but "parallel lists" is a very bad design choice. Better to use a list of dicts than a dict of lists for what you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

To debug a problem like this, it is wise to check the different steps you take.

When I execute the above code, the line:

`jobs=soup.findAll(class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard')`

yields an empty list.

You should 
a) look at the data that you receive (res.text), 
b) look at the findall clause you are using and if that clause is appropriate for res.text

Comment: how can i fix that?